# Not clear how to use the Github Notifications API

Tags: android, github, github-api

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/

I am trying to use the Github Notifications API to display notifications like

```
"someone followed my repo", "someone followed me", "someone commented on my repo", etc.
```

on my Android application.

Before using it, I tried to understand how it works.

When I tried doing

```
GET https://api.github.com/notifications?access_token="mytoken"
```

on Postman to see what if gives, it just gave me

```
[]
```

When I asked my friend to follow me on Github, I expected something to appear in the response, but it still gave me

```
[]
```

after my friend tried to follow me.

In what case do I get a response, and how am I supposed to use it to fulfill my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Axibase developed a set of handy tools that use the GitHub API to create and send Webhooks based on the events you're describing.

The workflow for the Repo Watch notification is shown here, it's the same for each tool just a different flavor based on the alert event:

[image: workflow-image]

The whole set-up process takes less 10 minutes, follows this [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/watch-notification.html) and runs in a Docker container which is pre-configured in the launch command. The procedure is goes like this:

1. From the Linux command line, launch ATSD with the following command:

   `docker run -d -p 8443:8443 -p 9443:9443 \
   --name=atsd-sandbox \
   --env SERVER_URL=https://atsd.company_name.com:8443 \
   --env WEBHOOK=github \
   --env SLACK_CONFIG="slack.properties \
   --volume /home/user/slack.properties:/slack.properties \
   --env ATSD_IMPORT_PATH='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axibase/atsd-use-cases/master/how-to/github/resources/github-watch.xml' \
   axibase/atsd-sandbox:latest`

(Remove the terrible spacing that SO requires for code posts)

**Replace the `SERVER_NAME` parameter with the public DNS name of the Docker host where the sandbox container will be running**

What you're getting here is a local ATSD instance with a generated Webhook. The command is bootstrapped for Slack, so you need to create an `.xml` directory on your local machine or URL with the following parameters and then replace the `slack.properties` template variable with the appropriate path:

`token=xoxb-************-************************
channels=general`

2. Watch the Docker Logs, and copy the Webhook. It will look something like this:

`Webhook URL: https://github:PdWnC1jF@atsd.company.com:8443/api/v1/messages/webhook/github?exclude=organization.*;repository.*;*.signature;*.payload;*.sha;*.ref;*_at;*.id&include=repository.name;repository.full_name&header.tag.event=X-GitHub-Event&excludeValues=http*&debug=true`

3. Open the GitHub Settings menu for the repo for which you'd like to create notifications:

[image: repo-settings]

4. Configure the Webhook by pasting the one generated at runtime into the appropriate field and configure the remaining settings:

[image: webhook-config]

5. Confirm connectivity (GitHub will do this automatically), and you're ready to go.

Use one of these other [guides](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-use-cases/tree/master/how-to/github) according to the event which you'd like to trigger a notification. The really nice thing about them is that they can alert via third-party messenger so the notifications are send directly to your smartphone instead of just through email.

Disclaimer: I've worked for the development team that writes ATSD, which is the database responsible for the underlying data processing and management tasks.

Good luck!